# ¿Como poner visible un div dependiendo del src de un img?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un carrusel de imagenes que solo consta de una imagen declarada en el html, pero en el archivo JS le digo que el src cambie dependiendo de que boton se use.

Además quiero que por imagen se muestre un div (cada imagen tendra un div) dependiendo de que imagen este "seleccionada" en el src.

Este es el HTML:

```js
var imagenes = ['images/ju_tboi.jpg','images/ju_mario.jpg','images/ju_cuphead.jpg','images/ju_minecraft.jpg','images/ju_goi.jpg','images/ju_mtg.jpg','images/ju_baldi.jpg','images/ju_doom.jpg'],
 cont=0;

 function carrousel(contenedor){
  contenedor.addEventListener('click', e =>{
   let atras = contenedor.querySelector('.atras'),
    adelante = contenedor.querySelector('.adelante'),
    img = contenedor.querySelector('img'),
    t1 = contenedor.querySelector('#txt1'), 
    tgt = e.target;

    if(tgt == atras){
     if(cont > 0){
      img.src=imagenes[cont - 1];
      cont--;
     }else{
      img.src = imagenes[imagenes.length - 1];
      cont= imagenes.length - 1;
     }


    }else if(tgt == adelante){
     if(cont < imagenes.length - 1){
      img.src=imagenes[cont + 1];
      cont++;
     }else{
      img.src = imagenes[0];
      cont= 0;
     }

    }

    if(img.src=='images/ju_tboi.jpg'){ 
     t1.visibility=visible;
    }
```

```html
<body>

 <div class="contenedor">
   
  <div class="atras botones">
   &#60
  </div>

  <div class="adelante botones">
   &#62
  </div>

  <img src="images/ju_tboi.jpg" alt="" class="imagen">

 </div>

 <div class="info" id="txt1"><p>The Binding of Isaac.</p>
 </div>
```

Ya probe varios metodos pero ninguno funciona, ayuda por favor.

Comment: Bienvenido al stackoverflow. Me di cuenta que estás tratando de crear un carousel sin añadir alguna biblioteca de mulitplataforma. Cúal es el link src para que se pueda funcionar la función carousel? Sin ello, no podría funcionarlo. Te recomiendo usar Bootstrap (actual version 4) que es lo más usado y de ahí podría servirte. Te dejaré una respuesta para que puedas entender cómo funciona carousel con Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

Bien, para poder entender la función carousel con html y javascript. Me gusta poner todo junto para entender la función.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es-ES">
<head>
 <title>Prueba funcion carousel 2 con bootstrap 4</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <!-- Esta es la biblioteca multiplataforma que habia mencionado antes --> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!--Esto es todo, se necesita añadir css, jquery, javascript y popper como se ve -->
<!--el estilo del css para funcionar carousel -->
 <style>
  /*Image totalmente responsivo*/
  .carousel-inner img {
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   margin: auto;
  }

  .carousel-caption h3 {
   color: #fff !important;
  }

  @media (max-width: 600px){
   .carousel-caption {
    display: none;
   }
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body>

 <div id="demo" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!--IMPORTANTE: el id se necesita relacionar con los
slides!!! -->
  <ul class="carousel-indicators">
   <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
   <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
   <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="carousel-inner">
   <div class="carousel-item active">
      <!-- la imagen del source dentro de la carpeta
que dejamos, sea una imagen con el nombre del archivo de la 
página -->
    <img src="la.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" width="1000" height="500">
 <!-- el caption de la imagen, titulo y escritura -->       
    <div class="carousel-caption">
    <h3>Los Angeles</h3>
    <p>We did have a great time at LA!</p>
   </div>
  </div>
<!-- No es necesario poner active, porque la primera
se activa y con el item toma todo como cadena -->    
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img src="chicago.jpg" alt="Chicago" width="1000" height="500">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
   <h3>Chicago</h3>
   <p>Thank u, Chicago!</p>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img src="ny.jpg" alt="New York" width="1000" height="500">
   <div class="carousel-caption">
   <h3>New York</h3>
   <p>We love the Big apple!</p>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- la funcion en html que funciona con jquery solo
con la biblioteca de bootstrap 4, ver bien el href
 que pide especificamente el div id del inicio, total
bootstrap deja los botones del anterior y próximo -->
 <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
  <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
 </a> 
 <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
  <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
 </a>
</div>
```

Esto es todo. Pero si necesitas saber más sobre las funciones del carousel,
[Documentación en inglés sobre la función de carousel en bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/carousel/)

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera teniendo en cuenta tu HTML.

```javascript
// Creo un array de imagenes, por cada imagen uso un Objeto para que tenga url y descripcion/caption
var imagenes = [
  {
     url: 'image_01.jpg',
     title: 'Descripcion 01',
  },
  {
     url: 'image_02.jpg',
     title: 'Descripcion 02',
  },
  {
     url: 'image_03.jpg',
     title: 'Descripcion 03',
  },
];
// Creamos una variable Index del activo
var currentImageIndex = 0;
// Guardamos variables de los botones, podes basarte desde document o desde el contenedor si tenes varios sliders (podes hacer un for para recorrerlos si queres).
var buttonPrev = document.querySelector( '.botones.siguiente' );
var buttonNext = document.querySelector( '.botones.adelante' );
// Guardamos la imagen y el caption a modificar
var ImageViewer  = document.querySelector( '.imagen' );
var ImageCaption = document.querySelector( '.info' );

// Agregamo un evento click a cada boton
buttonPrev.addEventListener( 'click', onPrev, false );
buttonNext.addEventListener( 'click', onNext, false );

//Creamos la funcion onPrev y onNext que van a sumar uno o restar uno. 
function onPrev(){
    // Si el index es igual a cero, no hago nada. Tambien podria llevarlo a la ultima foto con (images.length -1).
    if ( currentImageIndex == 0 ) {
       return;//No hago nada
    } else {
       // Restamos uno al index
       currentImageIndex--;
       // Ejecutamos la funcion que muestra la imagen y texto
       renderImage();
    }
}
function onNext(){
    // Si el index es igual a la ultima foto no hacemos nada (podrias enviarlo a la primera foto si quiseras y luego hacer el render.
    if ( currentImageIndex == images.length - 1 ) {
       return;//No hago nada
    } else {
       // Sino sumamos uno al index
       currentImageIndex++;
       // Ejecutamos la funcion que muestra la imagen y texto
       renderImage();
    }
}
// Creamos la funcion que rendera la imagen
function renderImage(){
     imageViewer.src = imagenes[ currentImageIndex ].url;
     imageCaption.innerHTML = '<b>'+imagenes[ currentImageIndex ].title+'</b>';

}
```

Luego puedes agregar mas interactividad usando CSS o modificando el codigo. Tambien puede utilizar una libreria, como https://idangero.us/swiper/